# Javascript array in SQL prepared statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, prepared-statement

Here is what I  am trying to do. I have a simple piece of java script code which takes the value of a checkbox and deletes the corresponding from the database.. Say that I have three options red, blue, yellow displayed and red is selected, the record for red will be deleted.

This code does it perfectly.

```
var n = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();
db.transaction(function (tx) {
                                tx.executeSql('delete from details where name = ?',[n],function(){
                                alert('The event is successfully deleted');
                            });

                        });
```

But the requirement is to capture multiple checkbox selections as well (i.e) if both red and blue are selected or all the three are selected, the code must deleted the records of the selected values. I am able to capture the values selected in an array with the following piece of code.

```
var checkboxValues = $('.myCheckbox:checked').map(function() {
                        return $(this).val();
                    }).get();
```

Now i need to use this array of strings in a SQL statement. I tried the following piece of code but of no use.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
                                tx.executeSql('delete from details where name in (?)',[checkboxValues],function(){
                                alert('The event is successfully deleted');
                            });
```

A few other answers suggested me to convert the array object into a comma-seperated string using toString() and join() function but those did not quite help me. I doubt whether my SQL statement is correct. Pls someone help me. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You are generating and executing SQL queries from your javascript? Hopefully your website is not publicly accessible.

Comment: Oh dear lord if you are building a library to execute sql statements client-side then you are allowing your users to take control of your database.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov or accessible by a disgruntled employee.

Comment: So true ... so, I hope your website just isn't accessible other than by you.

Comment: This isn't a website at first place. This is just a mobile application running on phonegap framework. Thanks for your concern. Any help guys ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could turn the function around so that it iterates over the returned values and preforms the db function for each in turn.  Something along the lines of:

```
    $(checkboxValues).each(function(tx){...
```

Or you could consider preforming the SQL update as each value is found within the first function, as long as you are throwing security out the window.  Then you would only need to include the value as a `this` and you could lose the variable.

Comment: I have already implemented this work around by looping through the array. But what i need to know is,how to get the 'in' clause working with SQL prepared statement in javascript so that I can work with array in entirety. Thanks for the help !!

Comment: In the long run, I think it will be easier for you implement your db manipulations from the server.  Otherwise you are going to be building work-around upon work-around resulting in a code that cannot be maintained, (but is easily hackable).